# InfopPath services with Credential Guard feature activated do not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have an InfoPath form which calls a few web services (some SharePoint ones and some custom ones) and retrieves some list items via an XML connection. They work fine in normal scenario but gives below error while I enable credential guard feature in a windows 10 machine. I would like to know if there is any possible action I can take from my end to get this thing working

Error:

```
w3wp.exe (0x029C)       0x23A0 InfoPath Forms Services           Runtime - Data Connections            7tfj       Medium            Data adapter failed during OnLoad: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.   27d28f82-1c88-4fdc-bcc9-e1d4927e0199


w3wp.exe (0x029C)       0x23A0 InfoPath Forms Services           Runtime - Data Connections            eq8l      Warning            The following query failed: a_GetList (User: user\xyz, Form Name: InsertLicense, IP: , Connection Target: http://test.com/a_GetList.udcx, Request: http://test/SitePages/createpage.aspx, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:createpage:-myXSD-2011-10-19T09-52-05 Type: DataAdapterException, Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.)
```